# Develop virtual keyboard on PlayBook

Tags: qnx, blackberry-playbook

I am tring to make virtual Arabic keyboard on PlayBook, I am using Air SDK, I this it not available to Air sdk, so I want to make it via QNX native NDK, to embedd it with the system keyboard

Can you please give me a example to how to do that?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to extend or replace the system keyboard on PlayBook